# Laravel - How to set HTTP response status code from Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, http-status-codes

I'm new to laravel and am successfully directing users tothe appropriate views from a controller, but in some instances I want to set an http status code, but it is always returning a response code of `200` no matter what I send.

Here is the code for my test controller function:

```
public function index()
{
    $data=array();

    return response()->view('layouts.default', $data, 201);
}
```

If I use the same code within a route, it will return the correct http status code as I see when I call the page with curl -I from the command line.

```
curl -I http://localhost/
```

Is there a reason why it doesn't work within a controller, but does within a route call?

I'm sure there is something I'm just misunderstanding as a newbie, but even the following code works in a route but not a controller:

```
public function index()
{
    abort(404);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't want to redirect, I want to load a specific view but have it response with a specific http_response_code.

Comment: I don't want to do a redirect. I just want to set the status code.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Copying your code, gave me 201. Clean Laravel 5.6 installation. Are you positive that your route is pointing to the right controller and method?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#view-responses.

Comment: Yes. I'm positive. Did you try it from within a controller?  Or a route? It works fine from a route, but not the controller (though the controller will return the proper view, just not with the proper http response/status code. I'm also using a fresh install of laravel 5.6 and playing with my first controller. (OS X 10.13.1 with PHP 7.1.7)

Comment: Yeah, it was from a controller. Not sure what's going on, since abort isn't throwing the exception for you either.

Comment: What happens if you die'n'dump in the controller? `dd('die')`. Does it give you a 500?

Comment: Your approach works for me. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#view-responses

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Solution

You could use what is mentioned [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181031021446/https://www.damchey.com/2016/04/return-view-with-custom-status-code-in-laravel/). You will need to return a response like this one:

```php
public function index()
{
    $data = ['your', 'data'];

    return response()->view('layouts.default', $data)->setStatusCode(404); 
}   //                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Notice the `setStatusCode($integer)` method.

## Alternative

You could set an additional header when returning the view to specify additional data, as the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses) states:

> ### Attaching Headers To Responses
>
> Keep in mind that most response methods
>   are chainable, allowing for the fluent construction of response
>   instances. For example, you may use the header method to add a series
>   of headers to the response before sending it back to the user:
>
> ```php
> return response($content)
>             ->header('Content-Type', $type)
>             ->header('X-Header-One', 'Header Value')
>             ->header('X-Header-Two', 'Header Value');
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I tried return response()->view('layouts.default', $data)->setStatusCode(404); and likewise it works when I call it from within a route in the web.php file, but if I move it so that this code is running from within a controller it works fine in every aspect except the http status code returns 200 when executed from the controller.

Comment: @climbd nope, I've just test it and it returns the proper status code (btw I used Postman to test it)

Comment: I'm going to download postman and try it, but I'm not sure why I get different results using curl -I  when a test from a route vs a controller.

Comment: @climbd try to do `curl -I http://the_route_of_your_request`, I've done it and it shows the correct status code.

Comment: I did. Everything you suggested was right-on.  So thank you for your help and sanity check. The issue was from outside of laravel.  I had been playing with different ways of integrating wordpress alongside laravel by trying different methods, corcel, a native install of wordpress, etc.  Well the native install of wordpress that I had left was getting in the way.  Once I removed the wordpress code it worked fine.  I then I was able to narrow it down to WP's template-loader.php file which I presume was loading and outputting blank data causing the HTTP headers to get send prematurely.

Comment: @climbd glad to help.